# Getting the initial emission of an Observable later in its tree

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android, reactivex

Given a hot `Observable<String> myObservable` which emit values at irregular intervals.
I would like to be able to `flatMap` an `obs1` `Observable` and depending on the result 
of `obs1` I want to `flatMap` an `obs2` with the initial `myObservable` value.
As an example consider the code below:

```
myObservable
   .flatMap(stringResult -> myObject.getObs1(stringResult))
   .flatMap(result -> {
              if (result) {
                    myObject.getObs2(stringResult); // Here I would like to get stringResult emitted by myObservable but I can't
              } else {
                    Observable.just(result); // We continue with the "same" initial Observable 
              }
   });
```

A solution would be to store the `myObservable` in a variable and get its latest value in the 
second `flatMap` but I wasn't able to achieve this neither so I'm looking for a more elegant solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the second `flatMap` into the function of the first `flatMap` like this:

```
    myObservable.flatMap(stringResult -> {
                return myObject.getObs1(stringResult).flatMap(result -> {
                    if (result) {
                        myObject.getObs2(stringResult);
                    } else {
                        Observable.just(result);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Indeed, this one was so obvious I dunno how I missed that. Thank you for your help